What happens when the logging category & the logging level matches those of more than one configured logging provider?
I was learning about logging and I read that there can be multiple configured logging provider, so I wondered what if the logging matched the category & the logging level of more than one provider which one will be used. I asked that question to more than one chatbot and I got different answers, which are:

All the matching providers will be used simultaneously
The one that is configured first is the used one

So what is the correct answer and is there a way to specify the provider to be used?

From the perspective of asp.net core services registration, all matching providers will be executed.
As we know, the services (Console Provider and File Provider) in Program.cs need to be declared in advance, and will be loaded when the application is first started. The code in this Program.cs will no longer be re-run unless it is restarted.
This means that the registered Console Provider and File Provider are working properly. So the qualified logs will be recorded by multiple Providers.
